# javascript fill input value with 0's till maxlength

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, numbers, fill

i have a input with a maxlength of 13 numbers.
Each time you type in a number it gets displayed on the site.

This is working fine but i need a default value of 0 for each of the 13 numbers if the input isn't 13 numbers long.

So if you already typed in `1234` the output should look like this: `1234000000000`

simply replace all missing numbers with 0

If the input is completely empty its working with `if (input == '')`
But I always need 13 numbers so I have to fill the input with 0's

```js
$('#input').keyup(function() {
  var input = $(this).val();
  if (input == '') {
    input = '0000000000000';
  }

  var i = 0;

  while (i < 13) {
    var digit = input.charAt(i);
    $('.inp' + i + ' > .digit').html(digit);
    i++;
  }

  var fdin = input.charAt(0);
  // getStructure(fdin);
});
```

```css
div {display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input" type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' maxlength="13"></input>
<div class="inp0"><span class="digit">0</span></div>
<div class="inp1"><span class="digit">0</span></div>
<div class="inp2"><span class="digit">0</span></div>
<div class="inp3"><span class="digit">0</span></div>
<div class="inp4"><span class="digit">0</span></div>
<div class="inp5"><span class="digit">0</span></div>
<div class="inp6"><span class="digit">0</span></div>
<div class="inp7"><span class="digit">0</span></div>
<div class="inp8"><span class="digit">0</span></div>
<div class="inp9"><span class="digit">0</span></div>
<div class="inp10"><span class="digit">0</span></div>
<div class="inp11"><span class="digit">0</span></div>
<div class="inp12"><span class="digit">0</span></div>
```

**edit:** made [this](https://codepen.io/creme/pen/rJRRwN) with it

Comment: Please update the snippet I made for you with necessary html - for example the `class="inpX digit"` Also why have inline code AND jQuery event handling?

Comment: To pad with 0s do `function(num) { return (num+"0000000000000").slice(0,13) }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ES8 [String.prototype.padEnd()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd)

> The padEnd() method pads the current string with a given string
>   (repeated, if needed) so that the resulting string reaches a given
>   length. The padding is applied from the end (right) of the current
>   string.

```js
var str = "123";
var newStr = str.padEnd(13, "0");
console.log(newStr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this approach:

```js
var number = 123;
for(var i = number.toString().length; i<13; i++) {
  number += '0';
}
console.log(number);
```

Also:

```js
var number = 123;
number += '0'.repeat(13 - number.toString().length);
console.log(number);
```

Comment: thanks is working aswell. But i'll use [void's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49068754/3711189) code. A little bit less code :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use **substr** technique by using the below code.

```
function myFunction(number){
    var newValue = parseInt((number+"0000000000000").substr(0,13));
    return newValue;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This could also be a possible approach when ES2017's `String.padEnd` is not available:

```
var maxLen = 13;
var myNumber = 1234;
var filledNumber = (myNumber + Array(maxLen).fill(0).join('')).substr(0, maxLen);
```